# Binocular rivalry in animals?

Tags: perception, measurement, experimental-psychology, vision, animal-cognition

Are there any experiments on binocular rivalry in animals? (In humans, brain responses to [Rubin's vase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubin_vase) are for example well studied.)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes! [Binocular rivalry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_rivalry) has been studied in monkeys** <sup>([Logothetis & Schall, 1990](http://www.psy.vanderbilt.edu/faculty/schall/pdfs/binmoriv.pdf); [Lehky & Maunsell, 1996](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0042698995002324/1-s2.0-0042698995002324-main.pdf?_tid=25af4bdc-d3cc-11e3-a725-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1399236131_ac69cb6c271b1998f5bdca29d8759e09))</sup>
**and extensively in cats** <sup>([Fries, Roelfsema, Engel, König, & Singer, 1997](http://www.pnas.org/content/94/23/12699.full); [Sengpiel, Blakemore, & Harrad, 1995](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0042698994001256/1-s2.0-0042698994001256-main.pdf?_tid=975fc6a8-d3cc-11e3-adba-00000aacb362&acdnat=1399236321_92dcf038bbf45976561c9b0473d1a312); [Sengpiel, Blakemore, Kind, & Harrad, 1994](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/14/11/6855.full.pdf); Sengpiel, Bonhoeffer, Freeman, & Blakemore, 2001; Varela & Singer, 1987; Moore, Spear, Kim, & Xue, 1992; Tong, Guido, Tumosa, Spear, & Heidenreich, 1992)</sup>,  to say the least. This is all the further I got into a literature search today, but I'm sure there's much more out there.

---

<sup>**References**

- Fries, P., Roelfsema, P. R., Engel, A. K., König, P., & Singer, W. (1997). Synchronization of oscillatory responses in visual cortex correlates with perception in interocular rivalry. *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 94*(23), 12699–12704. Retrieved from http://www.pnas.org/content/94/23/12699.full.

- Lehky, S. R., & Maunsell, J. H. (1996). No binocular rivalry in the LGN of alert macaque monkeys. *Vision Research, 36*(9), 1225–1234. Retrieved from [ScienceDirect](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0042698995002324/1-s2.0-0042698995002324-main.pdf?_tid=25af4bdc-d3cc-11e3-a725-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1399236131_ac69cb6c271b1998f5bdca29d8759e09).

- Logothetis, N. K., & Schall, J. D. (1990). Binocular motion rivalry in macaque monkeys: Eye dominance and tracking eye movements. *Vision Research, 30*(10), 1409–1419. Retrieved from http://www.psy.vanderbilt.edu/faculty/schall/pdfs/binmoriv.pdf.

- Moore, R. J., Spear, P. D., Kim, C. B., & Xue, J. T. (1992). Binocular processing in the cat's dorsal lateral geniculate nucleus III. Spatial frequency, orientation, and direction sensitivity of nondominant-eye influences. *Experimental Brain Research, 89*(3), 588–598.

- Sengpiel, F., Blakemore, C., & Harrad, R. (1995). Interocular suppression in the primary visual cortex: A possible neural basis of binocular rivalry. *Vision Research, 35*(2), 179–195. Retrieved from [ScienceDirect](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0042698994001256/1-s2.0-0042698994001256-main.pdf?_tid=975fc6a8-d3cc-11e3-adba-00000aacb362&acdnat=1399236321_92dcf038bbf45976561c9b0473d1a312).

- Sengpiel, F., Blakemore, C., Kind, P. C., & Harrad, R. (1994). Interocular suppression in the visual cortex of strabismic cats. *The Journal of Neuroscience, 14*(11), 6855–6871. Retrieved from http://www.jneurosci.org/content/14/11/6855.full.pdf.
- Sengpiel, F., Bonhoeffer, T., Freeman, T. C., & Blakemore, C. (2001). On the relationship between interocular suppression in the primary visual cortex and binocular rivalry. Brain and Mind, 2(1), 39–54.

- Tong, L., Guido, W., Tumosa, N., Spear, P. D., & Heidenreich, S. (1992). Binocular interactions in the cat's dorsal lateral geniculate nucleus, II: Effects on dominant-eye spatial-frequency and contrast processing. *Visual Neuroscience, 8*(06), 557–566.

- Varela, F. J., & Singer, W. (1987). Neuronal dynamics in the visual corticothalamic pathway revealed through binocular rivalry. *Experimental Brain Research, 66*(1), 10–20.</sup>